# iOS FBSDKShareLinkContent Share Post - imageURL not loading on Mobile Data

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, imageurl, facebook-share

I am sharing a Facebook post using FBSDKShareKit framework using FBSDKShareLinkContent. I am setting the content's imageURL to load an image for the post to be shared. The problem is, when I am sharing the post while on a mobile internet/3G connection, the link's image is not loading and shared on the post. Meanwhile, it is working fine when sharing the link while on a Wifi connection. To further illustrate, please refer to the screenshot below:

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQNBE.png

My apologies as I can't post images yet due to my reputation.

I am using the following code to make and share the content.

```
let content:FBSDKShareLinkContent = FBSDKShareLinkContent()
content.contentURL = NSURL(string: linkURL)
content.contentTitle = nsTitle as! String
content.contentDescription = nsDesc as! String
content.imageURL = NSURL(string: imageURL)

let button:FBSDKShareButton = FBSDKShareButton()
button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0)
button.shareContent = content
button.sendActionsForControlEvents(UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Tested with other devices, could just potentially be a factory defect on the iPhone6's 3G.

The testing is done by using 2 different SIM Cards on the same phone, same result. Meanwhile both SIM Cards are also tested on another device, different result. Speedtest is also done to check. both of which are comparable in speed.